# Separating img-tags with a single div-tag

Tags: html, css

I have a bar of equally sized images and want to insert a separator between each group of images.

The problem that arises is that an inserted div (as separator) between two img-tags causes a line-break. If I remove the div-tag, all images are aligned correctly in one line.

```
<div class="bar">
    <img id="id1"/>

    <!-- I cause trouble -->
    <div id="d">d</div>

    <img id="id2"/>
</div>
```

with the following style:

```
.bar {
    height:42px;
    color:white;
    overflow:auto;
    padding:5px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #0000ff;
    display: inline-block;
}

#id1, #id2 {
    background-color: #FFFF00;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

#d {
   width:40px;
   height:40px;
   background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

You can find this example at the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kreativgeist/38ta7chd/17/)

Thanks for your help
Joe

Comment: Use padding or margin for spacing rather than a div. That's what it's for.

Comment: `div` is a `block` element, use an `inline-block` element instead ( or learn to use flexbox )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your hints.
I changed that one line:

```
.bar {
   display: flex;
}
```

This solved my problem.